# How to use \marginpar with narrow margins

Tags: marginpar, fullpage

The `\marginpar` command is useful to create marginal notes in a document.  In particular, it is used by the `\todo` command from the `todonotes` package.  However, when the margins are narrower than usual, such as when using the [`fullpage` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/fullpage) to save paper, the marginal note doesn't fit and gets chopped off the side of the page.  How can we fix `\marginpar` so that it places the text inside the available margins?

In the following example, the word "elaborate" is cut off the side of the page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\begin{document}
There is a lot to say here.
\marginpar{Possibly elaborate here.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `\usepackage[marginpar=2cm]{geometry}` for example?

Answer (score 13):

The width of a marginpar is `\marginparwidth` separated from the text block by `\marginparsep`.

Any code that is changing the margins should ensure that the sum of these fits in the margin space.

`fullpage` doesn't bother, presumably because the intention there is to make the text block full width so that essentially there are no margins wide enough for text.

Given that, there is a reasonable assumption that there are no marginal notes.

However you can use

```
\setlength\marginparwidth{10pt}
```

or whatever width you need if you want to squeeze something in

Comment: 10pt is way too small, but 2cm does the trick.

Answer (score 7):

The `\marginparwidth` length is responsible for this, it can be set either directly (see David's answer) or using the `geometry` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[marginpar=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
There is a lot to say here.
\marginpar{Possibly elaborate here.}
\end{document}
```

`[image]

Comment: It should be pointed out that the `geometry` package must be loaded _before_ the `fullpage` package, otherwise it seems to cancel the effect of `fullpage`.

Comment: As you can see, there is no `fullpage` in my code and it's not needed, as far I as believe. You can achieve basically any typesetting area with `geometry`.